# Postgres - SQL error - violates foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3.

I have the following SQL:

```
WITH rem AS (
   DELETE FROM trip AS t
   WHERE t.end_date < now() - interval '10.6 year'
   RETURNING t.trip_id
), del1 AS (
    DELETE FROM otheritems AS o
    USING rem
    WHERE o.tripid = rem.trip_id
    RETURNING o.otheritemid
), del2 AS (
    DELETE FROM constraintviolation AS c
    USING rem
    WHERE c.trip_trip_id = rem.trip_id
), del3 AS (
    DELETE FROM currencyprovisioning AS u
    USING rem
    WHERE u.trip_id = rem.trip_id
), del4 AS (
    DELETE FROM trip_approver_snapshot AS a
    USING rem
    WHERE a.trip_id = rem.trip_id
), del5 AS (
    DELETE FROM requestforconsultantassistance AS r
    USING rem
    WHERE r.trip_trip_id = rem.trip_id
)
DELETE FROM caritemdetail_otheritems AS co
USING del1
WHERE co.otheritems_otheritemid = del1.otheritemid;
```

And I get the following error:

> ERROR:  update or delete on table "trip" violates foreign key
> constraint "fkf5b052b049daa795" on table "otheritems" DETAIL:  Key
> (trip_id)=(48288769) is still referenced from table "otheritems". SQL
> state: 23503

However, if I run the following, there are no results:

```
select * from otheritems o where o.tripid = 48288769;
```

This obviously has a row:

```
select * from trip t where t.trip_id = 48288769
```

**Question**

Do you know why I get the constraint error for the `tripid` if that row doesn't exist on the `otheritems` table?  How can I fix this so that the SQL runs?

Comment: If you have not made a basic mistake, like queried the wrong table, you are facing data corruption.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the reply.  My query was working perfectly before for other time frames. So I think you are correct, that there is a problem with the data.  Do you know if there's a way to fix it? e.g. can I remove the single row?

Comment: Yes, that would be necessary. But you shouldn't trust a cluster that has had corruption: Create a new one with `initdb` and dump/restore the database there. That will also show you if there are still more inconsistencies.